# WPF ignores d:IsHidden="True" in run mode (OK in design mode)

Tags: c#, wpf, hidden, expression-blend

Why is the left image hidden in Design Mode and NOT hidden in Runtime? It looks like WPF ignores the attribute "IsHidden". New empty solution, no single line of code - just Blend.

[image: Left is Design Mode - Right is in Run Mode]

Here is my code

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfApplication222.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="157.093" Margin="98.316,88.148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/img0.jpg" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" d:IsHidden="True">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-37.445"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="122" Margin="350,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/img14.jpg">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="13.144"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: have you tried rebuilding the project/solution ?

Comment: `d:IsHidden` hides element in design mode, not in runtime. Use `Visibility="Hidden"` to hide in both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the top of your XAML, you'll see the following:

```
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

This basically says *"Ignore anything prefixed with d: at runtime."*

You can either remove this line (not recommended), or use the `Visibility` property instead. Which will not be ignored.

Comment: It's not very practical to manually edit controls in xaml all the time. Is there any way to make `d:IsHidden="True"` behave like `Visibility` property?

I tried to remove `mc:Ignorable="d"` but VS throws an error:

The property 'IsHidden' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008'.

Comment: Not that I know of. You could do a Find & Replace (Ctrl+H), that should help to speed things along.